# Order Id and order View link showing different order id

Tags: product, admin, marketplace, multi-vendor, id

[enter link description here][1]In magento 2.3 multivendor marketplace When i am seeing my sales order from admin panel there i found order id which showing on Grid and order view link where order id showing is differ from grid's order id. This mismatching of ids create a lot of confusion when a customer orders the product from our platform . He/she getting order placement message according to View Link orderid.

you can see this video link for better understanding.
[1]: https://www.awesomescreenshot.com/video/3181610?key=f91c7fe7831ee2e97f0b2b91f8277d4f

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Id` on grid it is actually `increment_id` in DB, it generates in `Magento SalesSequesce` extension, `id` in view link is `entity_id` field from DB. They can be different if you used some `Custom Order Number` extension or deleted orders from DB.